# Incomplete array type int (*p_arr)[ ]?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, gcc, language-lawyer

When I compiled the following code with `gcc -Wall -pedantic -ansi -std=c89`, it compiled successfully without giving an error at the pointer assignment. Note that I convert from `int (*)[4]` to `int (*)[]`.

```
int arr[4];
int (*p_arr)[] = &arr;
```

Assuming that there is some reason for allowing this (incompatible?) assignment, when I try to use it, the compiler gives incomplete type error `error: invalid application of ‘sizeof’ to incomplete type ‘int[]’`.

```
(void) sizeof(*p_arr);
```

This error makes me think what is the use of allowing the previous pointer assignment `p_arr = &arr`? Is this assignment allowed as per the standard?

I have used incomplete struct/union type (usually for forward declaration) and also come across the error `incomplete array element type`. But this `incomplete array type` is new to me. Is it possible in C standard and has a use case?

Comment: Decide on one language. C and C++ are different.

Comment: @Lundin I understand. I always chose one tag so far. But which tag to choose if we are asking a question about difference between `C` and `C++`? Do you think these tags are meant to be absolutely exclusive or just meant to be some search terms?

Comment: @user1969104 Are you asking about a difference between C and C++? It doesn't seem so. If you were, it'd be fine to add both tags and I'm sure Lundin wouldn't have added this comment.

Comment: I moved the EDIT part to a new question [Difference in incomplete array pointer conversion rules between C and C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33782518/difference-in-incomplete-array-pointer-conversion-rules-between-c-and-c) as suggested by @Lundin. I will add both the tags there. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This assignment didn't give any error because their types are compatible because *arrays of unknown bound are compatible with any array of compatible element type.* ([For reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/type))-

```
int (*p_arr)[] = &arr;
```

But gives error on passing it as operand to `sizeof` operator because `*p_arr` is of incomplete type and you are not supposed to use incomplete types as operands to `sizeof` operator.

[N1570 6.5.3.4](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.3)

> 1 The sizeof operator **shall not be applied** to an expression that has function type or an incomplete type, to the parenthesized name of such a type, or to an expression that designates a bit-field member[...].

Now what you can use it, here is a simple example -

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    int arr[4]={1,2,3,4};
    int a[6]={1,2,3,3,1,1}; 
    int (*p_arr)[] = &arr;
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
       printf("%d",(*p_arr)[i]);
    printf("\n");
    p_arr=&a;
    for(int i=0;i<6;i++)
       printf("%d",(*p_arr)[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @user1969104 Please don't suddenly change the question with an edit. If you have a new question, then post a new question. As it turns out, your second question is related to the difference in pointer conversion rules between C and C++, which is not even related to pointers to incomplete type. Consider the example `intptr = voidptr;` in C and C++, you'll get the very same issue.