# Difference in incomplete array pointer conversion rules between C and C++

Tags: c++, c, arrays, pointers, g++

When I compile the following code with `gcc` and `g++`, `g++` gives error and not `gcc`. Note that the code converts from `int (*)[4]` to `int (*)[]` (which is pointer to incomplete array type).

```
int arr[4];
int (*p_arr)[] = &arr;
```

As discussed in [Incomplete array type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33777054/incomplete-array-type), `C` language allows this conversion. But why does `C++` disallow this and gives the error `error: cannot convert ‘int (*)[4]’ to ‘int (*)[]’ in assignment`. I know C++ is more type-safe than C, but does this assignment is really type-unsafe, because the later dereference of the pointer (e.g. `sizeof(*p_arr)`) anyway gives error in `C` as well?

Comment: What later dereference?

Comment: @ecatmur Updated the question with an example

Comment: @user2079303 I think that question in your link is taking about incomplete array type but not about conversion from complete to incomplete type, especially the difference between `c` and `c++` in this regard.

Comment: @Yeah, it seems to not be very relevant after all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conversion by itself is safe, but keep in mind that the same rule in C that allows this conversion also allows it in the opposite direction.

```
int main() {
  int array[4] = {0};
  int (*ptr4)[4] = &array;
  int (*ptrN)[]  = ptr4;
  int (*ptr5)[5] = ptrN; /* oh dear */
}
```

This is clearly bad. C++ has removed this rule, the rule that says `int[4]` and `int[]` are compatible types, and pretty much got rid of the concept of compatible type.

Some specific conversions that are safe [are being considered for inclusion in a future version of C++](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4325.html#118). They include your conversion as well.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this assignment does is really type-unsafe.

In C++, array types include the dimension. Always.

(Mostly.)

Comment: Why is it unsafe, as opposed to merely not allowed? (Also, I offer parameters of incomplete array type as counter-example.)

Comment: @AlanStokes: It is unsafe, and that's why it's not allowed. And could you show me an example of one of these "parameters of incomplete array type"?

Comment: @AlanStokes: That is not an incomplete array type. It is silently translated to `int* p` at the parse stage, an oddity inherited from C. Look up "array name decay".